# Observables with ngrx/store - race conditions

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx-store

I have a problem that I believe is due to a combination of my initial state in ngrx-store and trying to get just the initial response from an observable.  I'm using datatables, and large amounts of data for a static report - so I just want the first "real" response from:

`Observable.zip(this.sites$, this.devices$, this.machines$, this.machineContent$)`

In my ngrx reducer I have the initial state defined as [] for each of these.  However, at times there is (what I think is a race condition) where one of those observables will be returned as [], but the Observable.zip resolves, and it incorrectly renders my table at that point.

I've tried various combinations of:

`Observable.zip(this.sites$.skip(1), this.devices$.skip(1), this.machines$.skip(1), this.machineContent$.skip(1))`

and
`Observable.zip(this.sites$.skip(1), this.devices$.skip(1), this.machines$.skip(1), this.machineContent$.skip(1))
.take(1)`

And these work about 80% of the time.
I also have an observable of 'isLoaded' for each of those observables (machinesIsLoaded, machineContentIsLoaded, etc.) which I thought about using with `.takeUntil`, except that I'd have to check for each of these to return `true`, and it feels like I must be doing something wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you do `.filter(item => item && item.length > 0)` or something like that?

Comment: I tried that - the problem there is that the item could legitimately have a length of 0, so I'd like it still to resolve then.  Perhaps I could use filter otherwise though.

Answer (score 3):

First:  make sure your reducer is not ever mutating the array in state, because that *will* cause you problems.  Make sure you are cloning the array or using an ImmutableArray.

Second: instead of `filter`, use [skipWhile](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-skipWhile)

```
function isEmpty(table: any[]) : boolean { return !table || !table.length; }

Observable.zip(this.sites$.skipWhile(isEmpty), this.devices$.skipWhile(isEmpty), this.machines$.skipWhile(isEmpty), this.machineContent$.skipWhile(isEmpty));
```

This will ignore results until the arrays get populated and then always use results even if the arrays empty again.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using storeFreeze so it ought not be mutating.  I think my problem with this is the initial state - it always returns [], so using skipWhile in that manner won't ever matter.  I did, however, end up using skipWhile, passing in the isLoaded observables and just skipping until all of those are true.